# Wrong response in order to users input?

Tags: java

I have created a game in Java where the user get to choose 1, 2 or 3 dices and wins if the sum equals to 12. The game continues until the user type in the charater q. For every other character, texts or numbers (except 1,2, 3) the game says unvalid value and prompts the user again to choose a dice or type q to quit.

- If the sum is > 12 and the user has used all three dices, it counts as a loss.
- When the sum = 12, it counts as a win.
- When the user has won or used all 3 dices, a new round begin automatically and the user is now free to use all dices again.
- The user can only use each dice once in each round, so the user cant for example choose dice no 1 three times in a row.

I think that is where the problem lies. Sometimes when I run the program it doesnt act like its supposed to.
If I for example types 1 and then types a random character (for example h) it says ”unvalid value” and then that ”I already has chosen dice no 1”.

How do I fix it?

[This is a picture of what the system response can look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ig8DZ.png)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tärningsspel
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      
      //Declaration of variables int diceNo1;
      int diceNo2;
      int diceNo3;

      int sum;
      int numberOfWins;
      int numberOfLosses;
      int currentTurn;

      int userNumber;
      String userText;
      char userCharacter;

      String textToQuit;

      final int MAX_TURNS = 3;
      final int WINNING_SUM = 12;
      final char CHARACTER_TO_QUIT = 'q';

      // Values when the game starts
      userCharacter = 'a';
      userNumber = 0;
      userText = "a";
      diceNo1 = 0;
      diceNo2 = 0;
      diceNo3 = 0;
      sum = 0;
      currentTurn = 0;
      numberOfWins = 0;
      numberOfLosses = 0;
      textToQuit = "q";

      System.out
            .println("Welcome to the game-12! You are going to choose 1-3 dices and try to get the total sum of 12");

      Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

      do
      {
         System.out.println("Type which dice (1-3) you choose. Type q to quit the game");

         if (userInput.hasNextInt())
         {
            userNumber = userInput.nextInt();

            if (userNumber > 3 || userNumber < 1)
               System.out.println("Unvalid value");
         }
         
         else 
         {
            userText = userInput.next();
         
         if (userText.equals(textToQuit)) 
         {
            System.out.println("The game has quit");
            userCharacter = CHARACTER_TO_QUIT;
         }
         
         else 
            System.out.println("Unvalid value");
         }
            
         switch (userNumber)
         {
         case 1:
         {
            if (diceNo1 != 0)
               System.out.println("You has already chosen dice no 1");

            else
            {
               diceNo1 = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;

               System.out.println("You choosed dice no 1 and rolled number " + diceNo1);

               currentTurn = currentTurn + 1;
               sum = diceNo1 + diceNo2 + diceNo3;

               if (sum == WINNING_SUM)
                  numberOfWins = numberOfWins + 1;

               else if (currentTurn == MAX_TURNS && sum > WINNING_SUM)
                  numberOfLosses = numberOfLosses + 1;

               System.out.println("Throw nr:" + currentTurn + " Sum:" + sum + " #Wins:" + numberOfWins + " #Losses:"
                     + numberOfLosses);

               if (currentTurn == MAX_TURNS || sum == WINNING_SUM)
               {
                  diceNo1 = 0;
                  diceNo2 = 0;
                  diceNo3 = 0;
                  sum = 0;
                  currentTurn = 0;
                  System.out.println("New round starts!");
               }
            }
         }
            break;

         case 2:
         {
            if (diceNo2 != 0)
               System.out.println("You has already chosen dice no 2");

            else
            {
               diceNo2 = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;

               System.out.println("You choosed dice no 2 and rolled number " + diceNo2);

               currentTurn = currentTurn + 1;
               sum = diceNo1 + diceNo2 + diceNo3;

               if (sum == WINNING_SUM)
                  numberOfWins = numberOfWins + 1;

               else if (currentTurn == MAX_TURNS && sum > WINNING_SUM)
                  numberOfLosses = numberOfLosses + 1;

               System.out.println("Throw nr:" + currentTurn + " Sum:" + sum + " #Wins:" + numberOfWins + " #Losses:"
                     + numberOfLosses);

               if (currentTurn == MAX_TURNS || sum == WINNING_SUM)
               {
                  diceNo1 = 0;
                  diceNo2 = 0;
                  diceNo3 = 0;
                  sum = 0;
                  currentTurn = 0;
                  System.out.println("New round starts!");
               }
            }
         }
            break;

         case 3:
         {
            if (diceNo3 != 0)
               System.out.println("You has already chosen dice no 3");

            else
            {
               diceNo3 = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;

               System.out.println("You choosed dice no 3 and rolled number " + diceNo3);

               currentTurn = currentTurn + 1;
               sum = diceNo1 + diceNo2 + diceNo3;

               if (sum == WINNING_SUM)
                  numberOfWins = numberOfWins + 1;

               else if (currentTurn == MAX_TURNS && sum > WINNING_SUM)
                  numberOfLosses = numberOfLosses + 1;

               System.out.println("Throw nr:" + currentTurn + " Sum:" + sum + " #Wins:" + numberOfWins + " #Losses:"
                     + numberOfLosses);

               if (currentTurn == MAX_TURNS || sum == WINNING_SUM)
               {
                  diceNo1 = 0;
                  diceNo2 = 0;
                  diceNo3 = 0;
                  sum = 0;
                  currentTurn = 0;
                  System.out.println("New round starts!");
               }
            }
         }
            break;
         }
      } while (userCharacter != CHARACTER_TO_QUIT);
   }
}
```

Comment: Spelling: "dice" is already plural. While it can be used for the singular, "die" is the real singular. "Dices" is just as ridiculous as claiming the plural of mouse is "mices".

Comment: You should `continue` your loop in case of invalid input rather than processing the rest of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `continue` the loop as soon as invalid input is observed. Because you didn't do that, the `userNumber`, which was previously set to 1 goes inside the switch statement where it outputs that `You has already chosen dice no 1`

> The `continue` statement skips the current iteration of a for, while , or do-while loop. The unlabeled form skips to the end of the innermost loop's body and evaluates the boolean expression that controls the loop

```
     if (userInput.hasNextInt())
     {
        userNumber = userInput.nextInt();

        if (userNumber > 3 || userNumber < 1)
        {
           System.out.println("Unvalid value");
           continue;                               // Add this line
        }
     }
     
     else 
     {
        userText = userInput.next();
     
     if (userText.equals(textToQuit)) 
     {
        System.out.println("The game has quit");
        userCharacter = CHARACTER_TO_QUIT;
     }
     
     else 
     {
        System.out.println("Unvalid value");
        continue;                                 // Add this line
     }
     }
```